# Access Instagram data outside the scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, instagram

I just need to access my instgram data outside my the scope please help me with this. Everything is working fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function ()
     {
             var apiurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4322593457/media/recent/?access_token=4322593457.15d3a7f.13779606843446ab834b0e8512412d4a&count=5&callback=?";
             $.getJSON(apiurl, function (data) {

                  suatroot = data.data;
                 $.each(suatroot, function (key, val) {

                     var itemobj = val.images.low_resolution.url;
                     var hrefobj = val.link;
                     var captobj = val.caption.text;
                      data = captobj;  //Can I access this???????
                     var suatpaket = "<a target='_blank' href='"+hrefobj+"'><img src='" + itemobj + "'/><br>"+captobj+"<br></a>";
                     $(".instagram").append(suatpaket);
                 });
             });
         });
Console.log(suatroot); //undefined  here I want object
```

Comment: put Console.log(suatroot); at the end of  $(document).ready()

Comment: Javascript doesnt follow ajax request's response. Just runs line by line. So  after $.getJson javascript doesnt wait and passes to Consolo.Log line of your code and suatroot variable is undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will accept `suatroot` as parameter Like wise:

```
function suatrootCallback(suatroot){

   // code to handle suatroot/data.data

}

$(document).ready(function (){

             var apiurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4322593457/media/recent/?access_token=4322593457.15d3a7f.13779606843446ab834b0e8512412d4a&count=5&callback=?";
             $.getJSON(apiurl, function (data) {

                 var suatroot = data.data; // do not create global variable
                 suatrootCallback(suatroot); // call the callback

                 $.each(suatroot, function (key, val) {

                     var itemobj = val.images.low_resolution.url;
                     var hrefobj = val.link;
                     var captobj = val.caption.text;
                      data = captobj;  //Can I access this???????
                     var suatpaket = "<a target='_blank' href='"+hrefobj+"'><img src='" + itemobj + "'/><br>"+captobj+"<br></a>";
                     $(".instagram").append(suatpaket);
                 });
             });
});
```

Comment: And how I can access function callbackInstagram (data) {
    console.log(data);
} outside?

Comment: @AnupChaudhary, you can't. AJAX requests are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the instagram data only after being initalized, so better you can call a function after the response.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var apiurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4322593457/media/recent/?access_token=4322593457.15d3a7f.13779606843446ab834b0e8512412d4a&count=5&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(apiurl, function (data) {
        suatroot = data.data;
        $.each(suatroot, function (key, val) {
            var itemobj = val.images.low_resolution.url;
            var hrefobj = val.link;
            var captobj = val.caption.text;
            data = captobj; 
            callbackInstagram(data);    //accessed here
            //window.data = data        also if you want to access if globally after initailized
            var suatpaket = "<a target='_blank' href='"+hrefobj+"'><img src='" + itemobj + "'/><br>"+captobj+"<br></a>";
            $(".instagram").append(suatpaket);
        });
    });
});



function callbackInstagram (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Hope that helps! Thanks

Comment: And how I can access function callbackInstagram (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

Comment: just call that function as `callbackInstagram()`, or can you explain what you really need to do with that data.